# Function with many variables, diffrentiating. Hamiltonian and Langragian functions

Tags: derivatives, dynamical-systems, euler-lagrange-equation

If I have:
$$H(q,p,t)=\dot{q}_ip_i-L(q,\dot{q},t)$$

How can I obtain the following relations:

$$\mathrm{d}H=\dot{q}_i\mathrm{d}p_i-\dot{p}_i\mathrm{d}q_i-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t$$

$$\mathrm{d}H=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\mathrm{d}p_i+\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}\mathrm{d}q_i+\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t$$

What I asked is how can I obtain the last two relations from the first one.
Thanks!

Comment: Hamilton's equations: $\dot q_i=H_{p_i}, \dot p_i = -H_{q_i}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the total differential is an application of the chain rule for conservative dynamical systems. To implement the change of Lagrangian basis $(q,\dot q,t)$ to the Hamiltonian basis $(q,p,t)$ one defines what is called the "canonical momentum": $p_i(t)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i}$. One usually inverts these relations to find $\dot q_i$ as a function of $(q,p,t)$ and subsequently defines the Hamiltonian as $$H(q_i,p_i,t) = \sum_i p_i\dot q_i - L$$ The substitution is made in the definition of $H$: $\dot q_i =\dot q_i(p,q,t)$.